# Logitech C920 - Follow my face support for OSX 10.14

Tags: facetime, skype, webcam

I have had a Logitech C920 sitting on my shelf for over a year now and I just unpacked it to try it out.  I thought I would try the Follow My Face feature out because I noticed it working on other users (Windows) systems during some Skype meetings.  I am running OSx 10.14.6 and I installed the latest Logitech Camera Settings version 2.6.2. I opened Camera Settings up to find that Follow My Face doesn't seem to be supported.  Any suggestions (Maybe another application?) to get that feature working for Skype and Facetime?

Comment: This is more of a Logitech support issue. Have you contacted them?

Comment: @fsb - This, along with many other Logitech Mac support issues, falls under the "we simply don't care" category. Logitech's support for Mac has always been notoriously poor.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised their own suite even recognises it - it didn't when the C920 was new…

From [Logitech's C920 page](https://www.logitech.com/en-gb/product/hd-pro-webcam-c920)

> **Compatible with:**
>   Windows® 10 or later, Windows 8, Windows 7
>
> **Works in USB Video Device Class (UVC) mode with supported video-calling clients:**
>   macOS 10.10 or later
>   Chrome OS™
>   Android™ v 5.0 or above
>   USB port
>   Internet connection

So for anything other than Windows, there's no specific support, only as a generic 'UVC' device.
Many Mac users have complained about this over many years… as I got mine in 2012, I doubt it's anything they're going to be adding any time soon.

You can get a lot better than Logitech's basic support with a 3rd party app called [Webcam Setting](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/webcam-settings/id533696630?mt=12) [$7.99] & though it can't do 'follow my face' it does make the camera considerably more useful. It also hasn't been updated in 5 years, but then neither has the camera.
It works well up to Mojave. I can't test on Catalina, but at least it doesn't get the "May not work in future OSes" warning at launch.